# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in ASP C# Update Access Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, oledb

Okay, so here is the problem, i get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." when attempting a certain code to update my access database.
the update part is :

```
<%if (Request.Form["CmdEnregistrer"] != null)
         {
             cnx.Open();
             string sql1;
             string mat;
             string nom;
             string adr;
             string sexe;
             string ema;
             string tel;
             for (int bo = 1; bo < tmp; bo++)
             {

                 mat = Request.Form["matricule"+bo];
                 nom = Request.Form["nom" + bo];
                 adr = Request.Form["adresse" + bo];
                 sexe = Request.Form["sexe" + bo];
                 ema = Request.Form["email" + bo];
                 tel = Request.Form["tel" + bo];
                 sql1 = "Update Enseignant Set nom='"+nom+"',adresse='"+adr+"',sexe='"+sexe+"',email='"+ema+"',tel='"+tel+"' where matricule='"+int.Parse(mat)+"'";
                 OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql1, cnx);
                 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             } cnx.Close();

}%>
```

I've already ran tests on the mat/nom/adr.. strings to see if they received the correct content and it seems that way...

My database is set as : matricule is AutoIncrement Number, and the rest (nom/adr/..) is Text.
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

```
where matricule='"+int.Parse(mat)+"'";
```

Evaluates to:

```
where matricule='5'  // just an example
```

It's probably treating your "5" as a string. Try changing that to:

```
where matricule="+int.Parse(mat);
```

It'd also be a good thing to look into [parameterizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your query. It's safer and makes the sql statement easier to maintain too.

Comment: It worked! can't believe something as simple would have me working for 3 hours trying to find a solution! thanks a lot!